# redshift datediff not working when current_timestamp is used but working when getdate() function is used

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am querying a timestamp column with datediff from **current_timestamp**. But it gives error.

```
DATEDIFF(minute, timestamp_field ,current_timestamp::TIMESTAMP) 
or 
DATEDIFF(minute, timestamp_field ,current_timestamp)
DataType of timestamp_field is "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '2016-03-29 20:33:33.404256'::timestamp without time zone"
```

**OutPut:**

> ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not
>   supported on Redshift tables.
>
> Warnings: Function ""timestamp"(timestamp with time zone)" not
>   supported. Function "timestamptz(timestamp with time zone,integer)"
>   not supported. Function "timestamptz(text)" not supported.

But following query is working if I use **getdate()** function

```
DATEDIFF(minute, timestamp_field ,getdate()::TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: What's the datetype of your timestamp_field?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis : Thanks for your comment. I updated my question. its ``TIMESTAMP`` Datatype

Comment: Please do not tag Redshift questions with `postgresql` - especially if the function you are having problems with does not exist in Postgres

Comment: Out of curiosity I executed:

`select datediff(day, getdate(), current_timestamp);` and got the following error:
`function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", timestamp without time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist`
So I guess that current_timestamp returns a timestamp with a timezone and getdate() a timestamp without.

Unfortunately this doesn't explain your error message.

Answer (score 7):

I just simply casted the timestamp with timezone to timestamp and it was working.

example:

```sql
select datediff(min, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp);
```

Comment: that's not working for me. any tips?
`SELECT "reviewedAt", "createdAt",  DATEDIFF('hour', "createdAt"::timestamp, "reviewedAt"::timestamp) as hours_approved from "blackship$prod"."Application"` error [42883] ERROR: function datediff(unknown, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 36

Comment: i'm getting the same error ... any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`datediff('day', ref_date::date, actual_date::date)`